# Intellij, show innerclasses as members of a class in project navigation view of the file/class

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

How can I show the innerclasses that are part of a java class in the navigation pane? I believe eclipse has this as (+) and possibly already expanded by default.

Comment: IntelliJ allows to expand the class to see the inner-class by default in the `Project` panel.

Comment: @Bob.Z I can't see this. No classes except the class of the file is listed. No plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the inner class(s) and member field(s) via checking `show members` option of the `Project` panel, then you will see them after expanding the class. 
[image]

Comment: Too bad now you have to use the mouse to click open the file. Enter will expand the file. Life is never perfect!

Comment: 2018 is here ;), Command-Enter to open the selected file on macos, or whatever key binding for `View Source` action.